# Same Domain iframe cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have an image uploader (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) that uses an iframe as a fallback for processing. My site uses cookies to store the user information. Will the cookie with the user information be passed onto the iframe (I need to know the user's id when processing the images). The iframed pages is on the same domain as where the cookie is generated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if the iframe's source is the same domain as your parent page then any request originating from the iframe should send the same cookies.

Also, if you have Javascript being loaded into the iframe that should be able to access those domain's cookies as well.

Comment: As an addendum -- some browsers will disallow JavaScript communication across *sub*-domains, even if they have the same top-level domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you set cookies like:

```
set-cookie: some-key=some-value; path=/;
```

**YES**

but if you use something like:

```
set-cookie: some-key=some-value; path=/;
set-cookie: some-key=; path=/ajax-upload/;
```

**NO**